# how to display 2 different array in single array using for loop

Tags: php, zend-framework

My output is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [no] => 316198
                    [name] => Uma
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [totavg] => 3.0403
                            [tot] => 20.2023
                            [id] => 27
                            [pid] => 710600
                            [adr] => local
                            [photo] => 123.png
                            [date] => 19930-01-06 05:40 AM
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

and i want to show like :

```
{
    "no": "316198",
    "name": "Uma",
    "totavg": "3.0403",
    "tot": "20.2023",
    "id": "27",
    "pid": "710600",
    "adr": "local",
    "photo": "123.png",
    "date": "19930-01-06 05:40 AM"
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What did you try? And how do you generate those arrays?

Comment: Have you tried array_merge($arr[0][0], $arr[0][1])?

Comment: Next time consider reading some documentation maybe? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: 1st i just created my array, Array ( [no] => 316198 [name] => Uma ) and then i created Array ( [totavg] => 3.0403 [tot] => 20.2023 [id] => 27 [pid] => 710600 [adr] => local [photo] => 123.png [date] => 19930-01-06 05:40 AM ) finaly i assigned $result[] = array1[]; $result[]= array2[]

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive) to flatten your array and then use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) to create the JSON representation of the array:

```
$result = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, function($v) use (&$result) { $result[] = $v; });
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

If you know the key names of the sub-arrays beforehand, you could use `array_merge()` as shown in other answers, but those solutions will fail if your array is nested one level deeper, or if the positions of the sub-arrays aren't known beforehand.

Output:

```
[
    316198,
    "Uma",
    3.0403,
    20.2023,
    27,
    710600,
    "local",
    "123.png",
    "19930-01-06 05:40 AM"
]
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/139528)

Answer (score 1):

You could merge all array in one with

```
$resultArray = array();
foreach($bigArray as $array) {
    array_merge($resultArray, $array);
}
var_dump($resultArray);
```

Comment: That wouldn't really work if the array is nested deeper.

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge()` should work:

```
<?php

$new_array = array_merge($old_array[0][0], $old_array[0][1][0]);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($new_array, true).'</pre>';

// I see you want JSON format?
echo json_encode($new_array);

?>
```